# Kernel compilation of version 2.4 on a system running 3.2.0

Tags: kernel

My current kernel version on with my OS running on is 3.2.0.

Can I compile a kernel of version 2.4.0 on it?

Is there any perfect kernel documentation available? (As I see different ways of compiling kernel, expecting a unified documentation which lists all possible ways)

Comment: “Cross-posting is [strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073)” – [FAQ#cross-posting]. Crossposts like [Kernel compilation of version 2.4 on a system running 3.2.0](http://askubuntu.com/questions/268089/kernel-compilation-of-version-2-4-on-a-system-running-3-2-0) on [ubuntu.se] are not appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to compile a kernel 2.4 although because of the newer libc and newer compiler, you might get some compilation troubles... So you would need to create a sort of chroot environment with an older libc and older GCC, which is not that easy!

Just compiling it will not do any harm. But it might be too much work to do. So is it worth it?

Comment: Nope. For now, I go with compiling it on OS with kernel 2.6. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get an old distribution (there are several archived). But new hardware won't work, and much oldish software will feel archaic (or be outright broken in today's environment).

What do you want to get out of this? The questions you ask on the matter don't give any clue. It looks very much like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341): You want do do X, come to the (probably wrong, at least misguided) conclusion that to acomplish X you need to do Y, and ask about Y... and there are *much* better ways for doing X (if X can even be done using Y). Pray tell what you *really* want to do. Otherwise we will run around in circles having inmense fun comming up with ever more esoteric ways of doing what you ask, but you'll be not a step closer to solving your problem.